# Compare the values within the same column against other columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case, window-functions

I have a table as below

```
id      ParentName    HandleName       CreatedDate       
===================================================
139       MI          MI-Chart-QL       2018-02-20       
139       MI          MI-chart-act      2018-02-20       
139       MI          MI-chart-act      2018-02-20       
139       CRA         CRA-chart-act     2018-02-20
139       CRA         CRA-Chart-act     2018-02-20
```

I want to add a column with values - intentionally or unintentionally
if the HandleName with **Act** has the same id, CreatedDate and ParentName as the HandleName with **QL**'s id, CreatedDate and ParentName, then it is intentionally. The final table I'm looking for is

```
id      ParentName    HandleName       CreatedDate    Intentionally/unintentionally   
====================================================================================
139       MI          MI-Chart-QL       2018-02-20       Intentionally
139       MI          MI-chart-act      2018-02-20       Intentionally
139       MI          MI-chart-act      2018-02-20       Intentionally
139       CRA         CRA-chart-act     2018-02-20       Unintentionally   
139       CRA         CRA-Chart-act     2018-02-20       Unintentionally
```

The HandleName with 'CRA-chart-act' is Unintentionally because the ParentName doesn't match the 'MI-Chart-QL'

I used the below code (if Row_Number()>2 I can mark them intentionally) but how I can check if their parent names are same to mark them Intentionally or unintentionally?

```
Row_Number() over (Partition by id, CreatedDate ORDER BY createdDate asc)
```

Comment: The logic you suggest you require here implies that `Handle-Name` contains a delimited value, as `act` and `ql` have addition meaning. Is that correct? If so they should really have a separate column.

Comment: Unfortunately, table doesn't have a separate column that has ```ql``` or ```act``` but the logic is based on the HandleName that contains ```ql``` and ```act```

Comment: You could always create a new data set in a subquery or a common table expression that contains the extra columns, like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5442c9b993dcf1391f73ca0c9502633f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    case when max(case when handlename like '%-QL%' then 1 else 0 end)
                  over(partition by id, parentname, createddate) = 1
        then 'Intentionally'
        else 'Unintentionally'
    end as status
from mytable t
```

Comment: Nice solution, would not have though of this. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5fc6ef834c249e235b95d870748aaf4b) if anyone wants it.

Comment: This very much helps, thank you!. Is there a way I can avoid only two **QL**'s without  **Act** that are being marked as intended since it has the same ParentName, id and CreatedDate ?

Answer (score 0):

here is another way :

```
SELECT
    t1.*
    , CASE
          WHEN t2.Intentionally = 1 THEN 'Intentionally'
          ELSE 'Unintentionally'
      END AS 'Intentionally/unintentionally'
FROM
    mytable t1
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            1 AS 'Intentionally'
        FROM
            mytable t2
        WHERE
            t1.parentName = t2.parentname
            AND t1.CreatedDate = t2.CreatedDate
            AND t2.HandleName LIKE '%QL'
    )       t2;
```